I have designed an herosection with reactbootsrap and it's not shwoing in my scren
I've created an hero section ,consisting of a container with two different columns placed it .But this hero section isn't showing on my screen .What could be the problem?
import React from "react";
import { Row , Col , Button , Container} from "react-bootstrap";
import '../Herosection.css';
`function HeroSection(){
  
  return(
      <Container className="hero-section" fluid px={4} py={5}>
        <Row className="align-items-center">
          <Col className="hero-text" md={6}>
            <div className="text-section1">
              <h1>Your Clothes , Our Care .</h1>
              <h2>Expert cleaning for your favourite fabrics!</h2>
              <h1>Suds Wash Got you!</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="text-section2">
              <p>With a touch of experts cleaning,your cloths are left clean and sweet scented,
                Just the way you want it.Have a good time at your picnics,fun,get together's etc and worry not about the laundry work.
              </p>
            </div>

            <Button href="#" variant="primary">Read More</Button>
          </Col>
          <Col className="hero-image" md={6}>
            <img src="../assets/images/hero-image1.png" alt="hero-image" className="img-fluid"/>
          </Col>
            

        </Row>
      </Container>

  );
}

export default HeroSection;

`
So its a component ,and after exporting it in my homepage nothing showed.your text

`function HeroSection(){ -  why do you have a backtick at the start of this?

I think it was a mistake when I was pasting it here

It's unlikely anyone can find a solution to this just by seeing this component. It's possible error lies in the code rendering this component and not the component itself. Can you share minimum reproducible code so others can debug or possibly create a code sandbox with your project (atleast the parts required to see the error) and share the link so others can see the error you are facing.
